Priestly Garment
In Exodus 39 instructions are given that the garment of the high priest was to be woven so that it could not be torn. In Matthew 26:62-65, Caiaphas rends his clothing when charging Jesus with blasphemy.  The text says that he was at the place where the "teachers of the law and the elders had assembled (v 57)," and that it was near the "courtyard of the high priest (v 58)." Was he at home at the time and wearing "his street clothes?" Or, was he in some way showing the corruption of his office by wearing a garment that could be torn?
I am wondering if this is offered as a purposeful contrast of roles, as Jesus was said to be wearing a woven garment (as the High Priest was called to do) at the time (John 19).

The high priest’s garments, (Exodus 28,39) were special.

They carried the richness and beauty that surpassed the royal robes of
the mightiest kings of the surrounding empires. [1]


They were meticulously detailed, immaculately clean, and included a two-layered set of clothing that was worn all year during the rituals performed by the High Priest. [1] [2] The robe of the ephod was made entirely of blue cloth with pomegranates and bells along its hem, the turban, and the sash.[3] It was made in such a way, with a band around it's opening, so that it would not tear.  [4]
In Matthew 26:62-65, Caiaphas, the high priest, rends his clothes in response to what he perceives as blasphemy from Jesus.  (see this past question) 
This act was a formal sign of condemnation, similar to the putting on of the black cap by an English judge. [6] The judges in a Jewish trial for blasphemy were bound to rend their clothes in twain when the blasphemous words were uttered, and the clothes so torn were never afterwards to be mended. [6]

The high priest rent his clothes (τὰ ἱμάτια). His outer garments, not
his pontifical vestment, which he would not wear on this occasion. St.
Mark notes that he rent his under clothes, his tunic; so probably he
tore both outer and inner garments. This was done in assumed horror at
Christ's blasphemy (cf. 2 Kings 18:37; 2 Kings 19:1), rabbinical
injunctions requiring such an action, and prescribing the nature,
extent, and direction of the scissure. "This he did," says Chrysostom,
"to add force to the accusation, and to increase the weight of his
words by the act." His assessors, though fully agreeing with him,
appear not to have followed his example in this particular, taking the
high priest's action as typical and sufficiently expressive of the
general sentiment. The Fathers see in it a symbol of the rending and
destruction of the Jewish priesthood (cf. 1 Samuel 15:27, 28; 1 Kings
11:30, 31) [7]


In John 19, it is mentioned that Jesus wore a seamless undergarment or tunic, woven from top to bottom, beneath his outer garments.  (see this past question)  This garment was unique, as the tunic worn daily by men and women in Palestine was not seamless but made of two pieces of fabric sewn together. [9] Some scholars suggest that this seamless garment symbolizes Jesus’ priesthood, the transfiguration of the Levitical priesthood. [9]
So, it seems that there could indeed be a purposeful contrast of roles here. Caiaphas, the high priest, rends his clothes in violation of the instructions given in Exodus, possibly indicating the corruption of his office. On the other hand, Jesus, who is often associated with the role of the High Priest in the New Testament, is wearing a woven garment as the High Priest was called to do.
Some have seen this as a symbolic representation of Jesus as the true High Priest, fulfilling the law perfectly, as opposed to the earthly high priest who fails to uphold the law. However, this interpretation is not universally agreed upon and different scholars have different views on this matter.
